# How would I create methods that have access to the variables in main without parameters? - Java

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

So I'm working on a program that reads in a text file computes the mean and standard deviation of student's scores. How would I go about creating two methods that use the variables in main, but do not take in any parameters. I read somewhere that there is no concept of global variables in Java, so I'm confused how I would do this. I managed to create two methods that do these, but take in the variables in main as parameters(Not shown in my code), which is not what I'm going for. Would I have another class in my program or?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerReadFileSplit {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("NamesScore.txt");
    String[] names = new String[5];
    Double[] scores = new Double[5];
    int i = 0;
    Double sum = 0.0;
    Double mean = 0.0;

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String [] words = line.split("\t");

            names[i] = words[0];
            scores[i] = Double.parseDouble(words[1]);
            i++;
        }

        for(int k=0; k < names.length; k++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", k, names[k]);
           }
           System.out.println();

           for(int a = 0; a < scores.length; a++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %.1f\n", a, scores[a]);
           }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
      }

   //Make this a method called fndMean() using the scores array
    for(int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++) {
        sum += scores[j];
    }
    mean = (sum/(scores.length));
    System.out.printf("The mean of the scores is: %.1f\n", mean);

    //Make this a method called fndStandard() using the scores array
    double sd = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < scores.length; x++) {
        sd += ((scores[x] - mean) *(scores[x] - mean)) / (scores.length - 1);
    }
    double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(sd);
    System.out.printf("The standard deviation is: %.2f\n", standardDeviation);

 }
}
```

Comment: You can use static variables on the class.

Comment: you can do with static but why do you need methods with no parameters that would be evil when your code grow.

Comment: What's wrong with parameters?

Comment: *How would I go about creating two methods that use the variables in main, but do not take in any parameters* First, tell us **why**? Because that doesn't sound like a great idea (by which I mean, it sounds like a ***terrible*** idea). And you could use a `Singleton`, or a `class` level variable (`static`).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to move the scores array out of main and just make it a class variable.  So change:

```
public class ScannerReadFileSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("NamesScore.txt");
        String[] names = new String[5];
        Double[] scores = new Double[5];

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ...
```

To:

```
public class ScannerReadFileSplit {
    private Double[] scores = new Double[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("NamesScore.txt");
        String[] names = new String[5];

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ...
```

Then define you methods to calculate the standard deviation and mean deviation within the class:

```
   public void fndMean() {
       Double sum = 0.0;
       Double mean = 0.0;

       for(int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++) {
           sum += scores[j];
       }
       mean = (sum/(scores.length));
       System.out.printf("The mean of the scores is: %.1f\n", mean);
   }
```

Then of course you would need to call fndMean from within main.  The fndStanard would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can me the variables static which you want to access both from the main and methods. These variables are class variables and shared among all the objects of this class.

Answer (score 0):

There is something like Java static keyword, you could use it in this situation. If you want to have a variable and you want to have access to it without generating any object of this class, you can make it static. It means that despite generating many objects of a class, there is just one instance of static variable. You can use it also to count objects of a class.
There are also problems with static variables so it must be used attentively because they are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variables if you dont want to make object from class